# Unexpected date calculation result

Tags: java, time, localdate

I have a method to view a calendar in Java that calculates the date by year, day of the week and week-number.

Now when I calculates the dates from 2017 everything works. But when I calculates the dates from January 2018 it takes the dates of year 2017.

My code looks like

```
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.LocalDate;

// .....

LocalDate desiredDate = LocalDate.now()
                    .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 1)
                    .with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
                    .withYear(2018);
```

Which results in 2018-01-02 and it should be 2018-01-01. How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe the dayOfWeek index starts from 0

Comment: ON the Javadoc of the ChronoFIeld it says: Monday (1) to Sunday (7)

Comment: @SayanSil a) it doesn't, and b) that wouldn't explain the result `2018-01-02`

Comment: Yup. Checked. It starts from 1. Did you check for weeks other than the starting week of a year?

Comment: If you print out the incremental steps in the chain (`2017-11-13` -> `2017-01-02` -> `2017-01-02` -> `2018-01-02`) it becomes clearer what's going wrong.

Comment: Sigh... this is such an old problem with dates that are modified one field at a time, and has been a standard trap that programmers fall into for decades.  It's sad to realize that the new `java.time` APIs still have this pothole.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The order of invoked methods seems matter.
It you invoke them by descending time-granularity (year, week of week and day of week), you get the correct result :

```
long weekNumber = 1;
long dayOfWeek = 1;
int year = 2018;

LocalDate desiredDate = LocalDate.now()
    .withYear(year)
    .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, weekNumber)
    .with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek );

System.out.println(desiredDate);
```

> 2018-01-01

Note that the problem origin comes from :

```
.with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, weekNumber)
```

that sets the week number (`1 to 53`) according to the current year.
**The Java `LocalDate` API cannot adapt this value if then you change the year with  `.withYear(year)` as the week number information is not kept in the `LocalDate` instance.**

You can indeed see in `LocalDate` implementation that `LocalDate` instances are defined by only 3 field : `year`, `month` and `day`.

```
public final class LocalDate
        implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, ChronoLocalDate, Serializable {
    ...
    private final int year;
    /**
     * The month-of-year.
     */
    private final short month;
    /**
     * The day-of-month.
     */
    private final short day;
    ...
}
```

So to be precise, the important thing is that :

`.withYear(year)` be invoked before

```
.with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, weekNumber);
```

Comment: Tnx that did the job.

Comment: makes sense - methods adjust the previous result, they aren't evaluated at the same time. But I can understand someone getting caught by surprise due to this.

Comment: @davidxxx the original version adjusts to the first Monday of 2017 (Jan 2nd) then changes the year.

Comment: If you try to build a date by taking an existing date and modifying it one field at a time there are cases where it is not possible to set the date correctly even if you order setting by granularity.  This is a major pothole in the API.  The only reliable way to set a date consistently in all cases is to use a constructor that sets all the fields simultaneously.

Comment: @assylias I understand.  Thanks. I imagined that the API could do this kind of back change (adapting previous information with the new one).

Comment: @Jim Garrison Interesting thing but which constructor ? The `LocalDate.of()` factory method, doesn't allow to do what the OP asks.

Comment: @davidxxx each `with` returns a brand new immutable LocalDate (i.e. essentially a number of days since the epoch) that knows nothing of the previous operations.

Comment: @assylias It is right. Just `year`, `month` and `day` are used to represent a `LocalDate`.

Comment: @JimGarrison @davidxxx Yes, the `java.time`-API is missing a factory method for week dates like in [my library Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PlainDate.html#of-int-int-net.time4j.Weekday-).

Answer (score 2):

I want to mention, that there is another Problem(?) with LocalDate.

This Code does also create a wrong result:

```
    int jahr = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
    int woche = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);

    LocalDate year = LocalDate.of(jahr, 1, 1);
    LocalDate week = year.with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, woche);
    LocalDate day = week.with(wochentag);
    return day;
```

If you change the creation of the `year` variable to

```
 LocalDate year = LocalDate.now().withYear(jahr);
```

the code returns the expected result. It seems as the way you construct a LocalDate matters. I guess the timezone is omitted in the ".of()" version.